# How to Start Tomcat7 as root on MacOS

Tags: tomcat

Someone knows how can configure tomcat7 to start as root on Mac?

I Know it's not secure, but it's for internal testing purpose.

This is a related post, [tomcat7 ubuntu user owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148467), but I can't find an equivalent to `/etc/default/tomcat7` in my Mac, to change `TOMCAT7_USER` value to root

Some clue?

Comment: if you test now and determine that it's working, the big risk is that you're keeping to run as root. That being said, it's not only insecure but highly advised not to do. As state that it's for testing (frankly, I can't imagine what you want to test), you don't need it as a proper daemon, so just `sudo startup.sh` should do the trick. And I'm not giving it as an answer, because I don't want it to be voted on (neither direction). Just don't do it.

Comment: @OlafKock tks for your comment I appreciate your concern. I'm trying to make webMathematica to work on Mac Tomcat, and Mathematica support team asked me to test if running Tomcat as root would work (the answer is no), not a as final solution, but to find the problem.